# sublime alignment doesn't work

Tags: sublimetext2

When I use the sublime text 2, I install the sublime alignment, but the ctrl+alt+a doesn't work.See the screenshots below for more details.

[image: Before]

[image: After]

Comment: I think it's about update or something. When I tried some time ago it didn't work for me too, so I installed Align Tabular plugin (AlignTab).

Comment: I think it has to do with the font you are using. If you look, there are a decreasing number of spaces on each line (3, 2, and 1), which should align them properly. However, a space character is taking less horizontal space than a visible character.

Comment: In my case, it was working and than all of sudden it stopped. Restarting Sublime Text solved the problem.

Comment: In my case there was a conflict with Sublime Linter Key Bindings. So I changed them:
(Preferences > Package Settings > SublimeLinter > Key Bindings)

Answer (score 12):

You are using a font that has different sizes for characters and spaces. You want a font that has equal sizes for both characters and spaces. Those fonts are called monospaced. I had the same issue with the "Ubuntu" font, once I setted it to "Ubuntu Mono" it worked just fine. I am pretty sure that there are a lot of monospaced fonts out there.

go to preferences > Settings - User and edit the code there, save and you are done.

mine looks like this:

```
{
    "font_face"        : "ubuntu mono" , 
    "font_size"        : 15            , 
}
```

Answer (score 11):

I had the same issue with Alignment plugin.

Follow these steps:

1. Open the preferences file for Sublime Alignment:

   - Windows: Preferences > Package Settings > Alignment > Settings - User
   - Linux: Preferences > Package Settings > Alignment > Settings - User
   - Mac OS X: Sublime Text 2 > Preferences > Package Settings > Alignment > Settings - User
2. The file should be empty. Put the following in it:

```
    {
        // The mid-line characters to align in a multi-line selection, changing
        // this to an empty array will disable mid-line alignment
        "alignment_chars": [
            "=", ":"
        ]
    }
```

3. Save & close the preference file. By default, Sublime Alignment works with "=". Now it works with "=" and with ":". You may also add any other symbols.

Comment: in fact just a copy/paste of default setting into user setting makes the plugin work.

Answer (score 10):

Go to Preferences > Package Settings > Alingment > Key Bindings (default) and make sure that there is this code:

```
[
    { "keys": ["ctrl+alt+a"], "command": "alignment" }
]
```

Also check all the other key bindings for your other installed packages if there are some conflicts between key bindings (sometimes the same shortcut is used by more than one package).

Comment: the code is as your said and there are no conflicts between key bindings.

Comment: it showed me the package is installed...then package setting is not showing Alignment option...

Comment: @Onaseriousnote : goto C:\Users\{your user name}\AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text 2 and remove alignment package and then again install.

Answer (score 5):

Open sublime text, and go to Preferences>Browse Packages and find Alignment plugin folder,
Inside that folder create a new file "php.sublime-settings" and add below lines to it

```
{
   "alignment_chars": ["=", "=>"]
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Are you sure you're using Sublime Text 2 and not Sublime Text 3? I ask because I had moved to ST3 and the "alignment" package doesn't work for ST3.  I had to use the "AlignTab" package for ST3 to achieve this functionality. Should be able to check in the menu: Sublime Text -> About Sublime Text -> your build number should start with 2 or 3.

Probably isn't your issue, but sometimes it's the simple things that get us!

Comment: This answer is out-of-date. The ST3-compatible version of Alignment was released in August, 2013.

Answer (score 4):

#### Try `{ "keys": ["alt+a"], "command": "alignment" }` binding.

I'm on **Sublime 3**.
For whatever reason default `{ "keys": ["ctrl+alt+a"], "command": "alignment" }` that's automatically included on **Alingment package** install didn't work for me. I did try searching for conflicting keys, nothing found.
But `{ "keys": ["alt+a"], "command": "alignment" }` did work, now that's what I'm using.

Comment: Im using Ubuntu KDE with this same problem. I used to have vanilla Ubuntu and had no issues with this command. I didn't wanted to use this approach but didn't find any other option

Comment: As @AlwinKesler mentioned on KDE (at least kubuntu) it doesn't work. BUT you may disable the global hotkey in the settings. Afterwards it works fine again in ST.

Answer (score 1):

Go to Preferences > Key Bindings (default) and comment out line 564 to 568 like this:

```
    // { "keys": ["super+alt+a"], "command": "toggle_preserve_case", "context":
//  [
//      { "key": "setting.is_widget", "operator": "equal", "operand": true }
//  ]
// },
```

Answer (score 1):

In Preferences > Package Settings > Alignment > Settings – User
add :

```
    "alignment_chars": ["=", ":"]
```

Answer (score 0):

### In ST3 / Windows

**Key bombination**: `Ctrl + Alt + A`

In the plugin user config file:

```
{
    "alignment_space_chars": [
        "=", 
        "=>",
        ":"
    ],
}
```

To open this configuration file: `Preferentes/Package Settings/Alignment/Settings - User`